# declared value by mistake which is adding

Tags: javascript, function

```
var a = 5;

function total() {
  a += 5;
  console.log(a);
}

total(); //10
a = 55;
total(); //15
total(); //20
```

The output is `10-60-65`; without deleting the `a = 55` how to generate output `10-15-20` any idea?

Incorrectly declared value by mistake in total output as `a = 55` without removing that value how to fix it so my code run as `10-15-20` adding 5 number.

Comment: Sounds like a homework. What have you tried?

Comment: just working on that not homework

Comment: If cannot remove, can add any other code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a closure over the first value and use it independently.

```js
var a = 5;

const total = (v => () => v += 5)(a);

console.log(total()); // 10
a = 55;
console.log(total()); // 15
console.log(total()); // 20
```

Comment: without closure any thing else not want to go so advanced

Comment: if not, you need an instance to keep track of the last value, or a generator.

Comment: and yes i have to keep using the function too